# Estimate of basket volatility

Tags: volatility, derivatives, basket

We are looking for a simple way to calculate an approximation  of the basket volatility for a set of baskets so that we can estimate  which basket might produce the highest coupon in a standard Autocall product. We are aware that there are many other factors that may affect the coupon but are happy to have a simplistic approach in order to reduce the original potential set of baskets to a more manageable set which we can then price using MC.

Any help appreciated

Regards

Steve

Comment: Can you write the payoff / describe it, and also tell us what is meant by a 'basket', and 'basket volatility'?

Comment: Is the basket the average of the underlyings? Is it the Worst of the underlyings? Is it a *Rainbow* basket? What do the forwards of the underlyings look like? There are several types of basket and other factors that go into this, and also several kinds of autocall, so as @ArshdeepSinghDuggal mentions, we need a bit more information.